# Making Roboform cooperate with Fark.com

Tags: roboform

In general a wonderful program but it doesn't get along with Fark.com too well.  I have never been able to get it to work decently if you preview your posts--it likes to obliterate the comment in the preview window.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to set it so preview is useable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the way RoboForm works is by capturing form input fields on the page and storing these in a Passcard file.

If you edit the Passcard for Fark, you'll probably notice that the Comment field has an explicit value assigned to it (as do many other fields).

I think what you need to do is remove this field's information from the Passcard, by putting your focus on the field and clicking on the Edit -> Delete field menu item.  Save the Passcard, and try to access Fark.

Comment: If you delete the field it's going to bug you every time to save the updated passcard.

I would think that setting it to ignore the field would work but it doesn't.

Comment: How about keep the field there and use Edit -> Ignore Field instead?

Comment: I tried the ignore field--now it works.  It didn't used to.  They must have fixed something.

Comment: Good to know it exists.  I've have the same issues as you have with other sites.